# Wine fails to start Foxit Reader

Tags: windows, wine

When I tried to install Foxit Reader through wine, I got the following error pop-up window. Can anybody helps to debug this error?

> The program Foxit Reader.exe has encountered a serious problem and
>   needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> This can be caused by a problem in the program or a deficiency in
>   Wine. You may want to check the **Application Database** for the tips
>   about running this application.

Comment: A bit curious, why are you trying to install a PDF reader through wine? any specific reason? because there are so many alternative in ubuntu. Default document viewer is enough, another good one is `xpdf`.

Comment: Pretty sure Foxit has native Linux version, though when I last tried it it was under developed & essentially broken.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Foxit If it works it works ;)

Comment: otherwise http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/02/foxit-reader-work-ubuntu-linux/ :)

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on any pdf and choose to open with Foxit. Foxit should open with the pdf displayed. Then in Foxit's menu bar choose Edit/Preferences/General. Uncheck the box that says "Show Start Page". Foxit should now open without the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this problem by:

1. After installation through wine (instead of playonlinux) go to folder `~.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Foxit Software/Foxit Reader`
2. Delete the start folder completely
3. Start Foxit Reader